# "tienen que tener" como pleonasmo

Tags: gramática

¿Es "tienen que tener" un caso de pleonasmo y anglicismo (have to have)? Por ejemplo:

> Éstas son las habilidades que los graduados "tienen que tener" para prosperar en el mundo moderno.

¿Es esta frase apropiada para un texto gubernamental? ¿Cuál es una mejor alternativa?

---

Is "tienen que tener" a case of pleonasm and bad English translation? Is this phrase appropriate for a government document? What is a better alternative? See above example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No lo considero un pleonasmo ni un anglicismo. Más bien creo que la situación es muy parecida en ambos idiomas: los dos sentidos de "have" (poseer) y "have to" (estar obligado a) son análogos a "tener" y "tener que".

Yo preferiría decir, en lugar de "tienen que tener" , "deben tener" o "tienen que poseer" o "están obligados a poseer", pero lo haría para evitar la repetición, la diferencia de significado es mínima.

Agregado: aportan en un comentario la alternativa "han de tener" que también es correcta (ver [segunda acepción de haber](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/haber)) y usual.

¿"Tener que" es equivalente a "deber"? Aproximadamente, tal como "have to" es casi equivalente a "must". "Deber" se usa más para expresar una obligación moral, y "tener que" una obligación física o coacción. Pero es un matiz.

Comment: +1, yo creo que es totalmente correcto. Es cierto que puedes usar "deben tener" por aquello de conseguir una mejor redacción, pero no porque "tienen que tener" sea ni lo más mínimante incorrecto...

Comment: La respuesta me parece correcta, pero añadiré que en algunos sitios también se usa "han de tener*, aunque en otros puede sonar raro.

Comment: @Gorpik Buena observación. Agregado.

Comment: Es un pleonasmo, así se llama esta decisión sintáctica. Pero eso no implica que necesariamente sea un error. Hay pleonasmos "malos" (_salir para afuera_), pleonasmos intencionales, por énfasis (_voló por los aires_) y pleonasmos "inevitables" (_ha habido_)...

Answer (score -1):

por el hecho de que se repite un verbo ("tienes" y "tener") su sonido no es agradable. Por tanto, yo opino que es más correcto decir  "debes de tener".

Comment: Y "debes de tener" suena aun mas terrible. "Debes tener" sin el "de' suena bien, pero "debes tener" no es tan obligante como "tienes que tener".